# HttpPost return post page

Tags: android, cookies, http-post, httpclient

I want to post some message using `Httpost`.

I know values pairs that I need to post. I use `HttpClient` and `CookieStore` from an other `AsyncTask` that is allready executed. But why messege post page return itself??

```
public void postData(String login, String label, String messege) throws URISyntaxException {
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, Authorization.cookieStore);
    try {
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.x-bikers.ru/ls/add_msg_e.php");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action2", "post"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name2", login));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fmt_name", label));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("msg", messege));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "CP1251"));
        response = Authorization.httpClient.execute(httppost, localContext);
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStreamReader content = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), "windows-1251");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(content);
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
        }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using things from another asynctask? And what do you mean with the same page? If i use your url in a browser (GET) then it redirects to a different url. So with which one do you think you start?

Comment: @greenapps I use them because I stay logined on the website with them. So if I login I get message send form and when I post message it has to return sucsess page and not itself

Comment: To stay logged in? But this IS the login page as far as i can see. So there is nothing to stay i would say.

Comment: @greenapps If you try to open this url you will be redirected to login page.

Comment: Indeed. That is exactly what i just told here. So why do you need something from an asynctask that is already ended? What url was used by that task?

Comment: @greenapps http://www.x-bikers.ru/enter.php But as I say. I know that I logined in. I use several get tasks thats works fine with Authorization cookiestore and httpclient

Comment: So this is not the login page. This is a page to post a message. To be able to post a message you have to be logged in first. You logged in with a former asynctask. But posting a message brings an unwanted result. You get the page back which is used to post. What i miss in your story is if the message is received by the server. And you did not tell what kind of page you expected to be returned.

Comment: You are not determining response code or status code. Look what the value is. And responseMessage.

Comment: @greenapps  There must be simple page with title  "Ваше сообщение успешно отправлено". And no. Server not recive messege.

Comment: @greenapps I get 200 reaponse code

Comment: Allright Antoxa. Ask Pawel why these things happen. As a webmaster he should know. I cannot investigate for you having no account.

Comment: @greenapps I can give you my test account. Webmaster there is not comunicable

Comment: I will think about that. But then I need the other code with which you logged in too.

Comment: Can you tell me which .jar files you added to the libs folder?

Comment: @greenapps you can look at build.graddle file in app folder

Comment: What a lot of work to find all the right libraries and versions on the net. I have all but not com.github.dmytrodanylyk.android-process-button:library:1.0.1' . Please provide a direct download link for the .jar or send it me. I only found an .aar file ready.

Comment: @greenapps [Android Process Button](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/android-process-button/tree/master/library)

Comment: @greenapps I found an error

Comment: O yeee. Please tell. There is missing some Theme file I think. Because in styles_xbikers.xml   `<style name="Theme.Xbikers" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">` cannot be found. Also in the manifest file alll style Theme's cannot be found. What is missing. For the rest i think that i know what goes wrong after login. Thats because you start a browser then. Or not?

Comment: It was a big task to import all. All cyrillic utf-8 was gone. So i had to copy and past many source files by hand and save in utf-8. The manifest file is slightly different in Eclipse too. At one moment i could login but after Autorisation you test the title of the page for X-Bikers and so on. But as the ciryllic was gone the login seemed to fail. But.... you write very beautifull code! Респект!

Comment: @greenapps About resources. It is compability error.
About question. In ReadMessageActivity, i use text field author, to set post login. That textfield contains "Some text" + author. So when I try to post message, there was incorrect login.

Comment: It starts with LoginActivity. Then runs an Autorization task upon which in onPostExecute BikerAnketeActivity is started. This activity displays enter_button "Открыть". Pressing this button starts an external browser for profile_uri. There the user can click on "Написать ››››". This brings a page where you have to  login (again). Is this intended behaviour? Where can i find the postData() fuction you posted here? (I found one in Autorization task already).